# Given that $f(x) = x^k$ where $k < 0$, what is the range of $f(x)$ on the interval $[1, \infty)$?

Tags: functions

Not sure how to solve this question. I set $f(x)$ as $y$ and tried rewriting $x$ as $\sqrt[k]{y}$ – then break it up into cases where $x>0$ and $x<0$. But that didn't exactly work out since it got a little confusing... A bit help?
Also, edit: When they say, $[1, \infty)$, do they mean the domain or range or something else?

Comment: How can $x$ be negative when it is given to be in $[1,\infty)$?

Comment: You can ignore my first attempt – I was pretty sure it was wrong anyways, sorry about that.

Comment: The answer is $(0,1]$? Can you justify it?

Comment: @geetha290krm Do you mean that the $[1, \infty)$ is describing the domain?

Comment: Have you tried drawing a rough graph? Have you tried some easy values of $k$ to see what might be going on?

Comment: Not sure how to graph it because you don't know what $k$ is, so the most I can do is to set an example value for $k$, but how will that help generally?

Comment: @chantria Yes, that means the domain

Comment: @chantria Drawing a graph may be helpful, as it is a way to see visually what might be going on. In your case, it is ok to choose an example value for $k$ and work from there. The general behavior will be essentially the same, regardless of the specific value of $k$.

Comment: Oh ok, thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the equation equivalent to y=f(x), x=$\frac{1}{\sqrt[k]{y}}$. $Since\, x\in [1,+\infty)$ we obtain $ y>0\,y\leq 1 $ and hence Range =(0,1].

Answer (score 0):

Just plug it in:
Since k<0,if you plug a 1 in, f(x) = 1. If x is super large,the output approaches 0 but never reaches it. So the answer is (0, 1]